PWA opens a new Chrome tab on Pixel 4a
I use a Pixel 4A with the latest Android 13 (the model doesn't support Android 14).
When creating a PWA via Chrome "Add to Home Screen", an "app" is created but every time it opens it just acts as a normal shortcut (opens as a new tab in Chrome browser)
The same website (https://reflect.app) created as PWA on my Samsung Galaxy S22, Android 14 has no issue.
I try using the bit.ly link hack and using "shortcut maker" but no luck.
Is there any solution to this?

Hmm, no repro'd on Pixel 3a, Android 12L, Chrome... The site was installed as an app (shown on the app launcher, which can be uninstalled) and opened as a standalone Chrome Custom Tab. At first, I thought it was because there was no PWA manifest on the website, but I guess it's irrelevant.

It maybe some setting on that device ? firefox does the same !
